# Returning and passing cv vector KeyPoint c++ python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to write Python bindings for C++ codes following [this link](https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-convert-your-opencv-c-code-into-a-python-module/) and [this explanation by OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html).

While I know how to pass and return `cv::Mat`, (using `OutputArray`) as they get converted to numpy arrays, I'm having trouble returning complex elements.

How do I return a `std::vector<cv::Keypoints>` element? The guide says we can use `CV_OUT` but I couldn't get it to work.  Any tutorial would be helpful. I am simply trying to modify the C++ code in the tutorial by adding a few dummy keypoints and trying to return then.